# JS and CSS animation resists my attempts to make it work in reverse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get this animation to work backwards as well, but it seems to always start from the first element from top down, despite my reversal of the index... I also can't get the initial navbar to fade in, but maybe that's a symptom of a deeper problem. I've run the code with console.log, to try and diagnose the problem, and it seems like the for loop isn't even running, which doesn't make sense to me - there's nothing stopping it. Outside of that, everything else *seems* right

Please help!

```js
            var buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('button'));
            document.getElementById("expandBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
                buttons.forEach(button => {
                    button.classList.add("hide");
                    button.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
                        this.style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("hiddenNavigation").style.minHeight = '55px';
                    })
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("hiddenNavigation").classList.add("show");
                    document.getElementById("back").classList.add("show");
                    let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navWrapper button');
                    listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
                        item.style.transitionDelay = `${index * 0.1}s`;
                    });
                }, 250);
            });

            document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("oh");
                document.getElementById("back").classList.remove("show");
                document.getElementById("hiddenNavigation").classList.remove("show");
                let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
                let length = listItems.length;
                document.getElementById("hiddenNavigation").style.minHeight = 'auto';
                for (let index = length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
                    let item = listItems[index];
                    item.style.transitionDelay = `${(length - 1 - index) * 0.1}s`;
                }
                let done = true;
                
                buttons.forEach(button => {
                    button.classList.remove("hide");
                    button.style.display = "inherit";
                })
            });
```

```css
header {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #bfb398;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

header img {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 2;
}

header button {
    font-family: 'Ageo';
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background: none;
    font-size: 7.9vmin;
}

#back {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width: 42px;
    filter: invert(100%);
}

#back.show {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 2%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}

header .button {
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
}

header .button.hide {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
}

#hiddenNavigation {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .65s ease-in-out;
}

#hiddenNavigation .navWrapper {
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

#hiddenNavigation button {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family: 'Arcuata';
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(35%, -5px, 0);
    transition: transform .35s ease-in-out, opacity .37s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#hiddenNavigation.show {
    max-height: 254px; 
}

#hiddenNavigation.show button {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#oval {
    border: 1px solid #bfb398;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 135px;
    left: 9px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 140px;
    margin:10px 0 0 -10px;  
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 140px / 77px;
    clip-path: inset(70px 28px 70px 28px);
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -164px;
}

/* Navbar */
[aria-label="Navigation Bar"] {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#AC0836, #8C062C);
    border: 1px solid #E28C4A;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    outline: 1px solid #BC3B30;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: -135px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 145px;
}

.initialNavigation {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5vw;
    justify-content: center;
}

.initialNavigation button:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: "•";
    margin-left: 4vw;
    color: rgb(240, 157, 180);
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <div id="oval" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        </div>
            <section aria-label="Navigation Bar">
                <nav class="initialNavigation">
                    <button aria-description="Link to Ice Cream Menu" class="button">Menu</button>
                    <button aria-description="Opens hidden altnerate menu" class="button" id="expandBtn">Explore</button>
                    <button aria-description="Link to shipping options for merchandise and ice cream" class="button">Ship</button>
                </nav>
                <nav id="hiddenNavigation" class="hidden">
                    <img id="back" src="Images/Back-Arrow.svg" title="Back arrow"
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async">
                    <div class="navWrapper">
                        <button aria-description="Links to description of Stratton Leopold, founder of Leopolds">Our Founder</button>
                        <button aria-description="Link to Leopold's blog" >Blog</button>
                        <button aria-description="Link to Merchandise shop" >Shop</button>
                        <button aria-description="Link to Leopold's locations addresses">Locations</button>
                        <button aria-description="Link to catering and events">Ice Cream Socials</button>
                        <button aria-description="Link to about page">About</button>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </section>
    </header>
```

Comment: `let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');` here is an empty nodelist, you don't have `.list-item`.

Answer (score 0):

In the back event listener you're querying for something that doesn't exist:

```js
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
```

You actually want:

```js
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navWrapper button');
```